# How to pass a function to another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need some help passing a function to my second class. I have tried many things but it still not work.

```swift
class Main {
    func one() {
        let test = Sub(function: two)
    }
    func two(val: Int, completion: ((Int, String)?)->()) { }
}

class Sub {
    var function: (Int, ((Int, String)?)->())
    init(function: (Int, ((Int, String)?)->())) {
        self.function = function
    }
}
```

Why is it that i get error on this line

```
let test = Sub(function: two)
```

which says: `Cannot convert value of type '(Int, ((Int, String)?) -> ()) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Int, ((Int, String)?) -> ())'`

What is the reason?

Comment: The closure must be`@escaping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function has a return value plus the completion , you need to change syntax of `function` var inisde `Sub` and the `init` also

```
class Main {
    func one() {

        let test = Sub(function: two)
    }
    func two(val: Int, completion: ((Int, String)?)->()) { }
}

class Sub {
    var function: ((Int, ((Int, String)?)->())) -> ()
    init(function:@escaping ((Int, ((Int, String)?)->())) -> ()) {
        self.function = function
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove unnecessary parentheses & `-> () `around `completion` and use `Void` in-place of `()` for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

@escaping need to be added

```
 class Main {
        func one() {
            let test = Sub(function: two)
        }
        func two(val: Int, completion: (Int, String)?)->() { }
    }

class Sub {
    var function: (Int, (Int, String)?)->()
    init(function: @escaping (Int, (Int, String)?)->()) {
        self.function = function
    }
}
```

Comment: This one can't work. You have changed the function signature of function `two` to have a completion tupple instead of a closure.